# Git commits local changes which are not added - how can I stop this?

Tags: git, commit

I'm new to Git and use Git Bash locally. I have an issue when committing.
As I learned, changes are only committed after they have been staged via `add` (unless you are using `commit -a`). But in contrast, I face the following scenario:

I add a file test.txt: `git add test.txt`

After that, I do some changes locally to this file without a further add.
`git status` shows me - still as expected - changes to be committed and changes not staged for commit.

So far so good, but now it's getting irritating: I do a `git commit -m "commit only staged changes" test.txt`
But as a result, my local changes are committed as well.
Also, `git status`now only says "nothing to commit, working tree clean".

Can anybody explain to me, what needs to be done that only the staged changes are committed (what I actually understood as default behaviour...)?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you give a specific filename, as in

```
git commit [options] test.txt
```

then git will forego its default behavior and instead immediately commit *all changes to that file*. In this mode, it does *not* commit other changes that you have already staged.

If you want to commit only the staged changes, simply leave out the filename.

```
git commit [options]
```

Note that there is no way to commit only the staged changes to a single file while skipping both unstaged changes to that same file *and* staged changes to other files. You can either commit all staged changes (regardless of what files they are in), or you can commit all changes (staged or not) to one or more files. However, you can unstage changes to other files before committing, using `git restore <filename>` (if your version of Git is new enough to have it) or `git reset <filename>`.

Comment: Thx a lot for this precise answer. Very helpful to better understand the git logic :)